# Dynamically set the source (workbook) for the Sharepoint 2013 EWA (Excel Web Access)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am trying to dynamically set the source (workbook) for the Sharepoint 2013 EWA (Excel Web Access) from a SP (sharepoint) list that will contain the excel workbooks. I have searched the internet for a solution using jquery/JS but i haven't had any success.

The other possible way that a college proposed was to use connected web parts but I am still a little vague on how that will achieve my desired results.

Is there any way of achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The standard structure of EWA URL is: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/tw/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={FF2FDEBB-67AA-4061-952C-647942D56596}&file=filename.xlsx&action=default

The minimal is:
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/tw/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={UniqueId of the file}

You can place IFRAME element on your page and change it's SRC attribute using JS to display excel file you want.